# Length of input characters in Ruby

Tags: ruby

In Python, the output of length of input characters is:

```
age=input("Your age:")
print(len(age))
```

When we put `33`, we get `2`. In Ruby, for:

```
print "Your age:"
age=gets
print age.length
```

the output is `3`. Why are they different?

Comment: Might have helped if you also read the doco for input in python and gets in ruby

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why they are different ?

It's because in the second example there is a newline symbol also counted `\n`. Check it:

```
print "Your age:"
age=gets
print age
"33\n"
print age.chomp.length #  without newline
#> 2
print age.length #  with newline
#> 3
```

[`chomp`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-chomp)

> Returns a new String with the given record separator removed from the
>   end of str (if present).

[`gets`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Kernel.html#method-i-gets)

> .... The separator is included with the contents of each record....

<sub>I advise you to read first the documentation for the methods what are you using. It's much more better for education, than post a question and wait an answer.</sub>

Comment: Awesome, Thank you.

Comment: _"where paragraphs are divided by two consecutive newlines"_ refers to a zero-length separator, i.e. `''`. The relevant part is the sentence before: _"The separator is included with the contents of each record."_